# /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long (mass renaming files)

Tags: bash, shell, find, rename

I am trying to mass rename some files by truncating the files where the first space occurs in the file name. I have written a simple script to do this with rename as such:

```
for i in *.fa; do rename 's/\s.*//' *.fa; done
```

This works just fine in a test and produces the following results as desired:

```
$:~/testenv$ ls
NM_000016.5_LastMex1_4_12 23 0 1 KB882088_3062975-30.fa  NM_000016.5_PastMex1_4_12 23 0 1 KB882088_3062975-30.fa
$:~/testenv$ for i in *.fa; do rename 's/\s.*//' *.fa; done
$:~/testenv$ ls
NM_000016.5_LastMex1_4_12  NM_000016.5_PastMex1_4_12
```

Unfortunately I have to do this on a lot of files, about 6.7 million. This is giving me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long
```

I've tried every sort of trick I can think of, even when I use find it can't seem to pick up the files.

```
$:~/testenv$ ls
NM_000016.5_astMex1_4_12 23 0 1 KB882088_3062975-30.fa   NM_000016.5_PastMex1_4_12 23 0 1 KB882088_3062975-30.fa
NM_000016.5_LastMex1_4_12 23 0 1 KB882088_3062975-30.fa    
$:~/testenv$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'rename 's/\s.*//' *.fa' _ {} \;
find: `./NM_000016.5_PastMex1_4_12 23 0 1 KB882088_3062975-30.fa': No such file or directory
find: `./NM_000016.5_astMex1_4_12 23 0 1 KB882088_3062975-30.fa': No such file or directory
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `for i in *.fa; do rename 's/\s.*//' *.fa; done`, when it works, renames all your .fa files *once for each file*, meaning, if you have 1000 files, you're renaming all 1000 files 1000 times, for a total of 1,000,000 potential operations. Surely that's not what you want.

Comment: Those `ls` examples would be easier to read if replaced with `ls -1Q` examples.  (The `-1Q` lists one item per line, *quoted*.)

Comment: @agc, ...though being a non-POSIX extension, there's no guarantee that the OP (or anyone else) has it available.

Answer (score 11):

You have this bug because you use `*.fa` not just as the glob to iterate over, but also expand it onto the command line of an individual `rename` command, where that list of names overruns your operating system's maximum argument vector length. You won't have that issue with the following:

```
# run rename once per *.fa file, with only one name given each run
for i in *.fa; do rename 's/\s.*//' "$i"; done
```

...or its more-efficient cousin:

```
# only tries to rename files that actually have a space in their name
# runs "rename" only as many times as necessary -- not once per file, like the above.
find . -name '*[[:space:]]*.fa' -exec rename 's/\s.*//' {} +
```

---

That said, the external `rename` command isn't strictly required for this use case at all.

```
# Rename all files with a space in their name, then ending in .fa, to truncate at the space
for i in *[[:space:]]*.fa; do
  mv -- "$i" "${i%%[[:space:]]*}"
done
```

If you want to keep the extension, that may instead be:

```
for i in *[[:space:]]*.fa; do
  mv -- "$i" "${i%%[[:space:]]*}.fa"
done
```

Comment: Surely you don't want to execute `mv` 6.7 million times? Isn't that good reason to stick with `find -exec rename {} +`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, ah, but is it really 6.7 million files that *need* renaming? I'm guessing here that we were passing a whole lot of names to `rename` which were already fine -- hence refining the glob to look for only for names with a space in them.

Comment: @charles-duffy hey thanks, your solution worked pretty well. One thing that happened though is I got a `no space left on device` error in the middle of it on a handful of files. Which is weird because I have assloads of space. Any ideas?
`/dev/dm-0               17T  252G   16T   2% /`

Comment: @charles-duff and yes all 6.7 million files needed renaming. They all have spaces.

Comment: @bhffs, I'd suggest looking at your free inodes, as opposed to only free blocks.